# Facing an issue with Magento 2.2.9 version

Tags: magento, magento2, traffic

My sites get down every 2-3 days. It doesn't show any error on upfront, the browser keeps on loading for a very long time, but no data appears. When I check the apache error logs I found Max Request Workers limit exhausted. For the last 10 days, I am increasing the same the frequency is increased to 5days but still getting down. The site was launched 45 days ago, running perfectly for 30 days. Even we have not observed any hike in the traffic. The site is hosted at the AWS plan is t2.2xlarge.

Comment: Have you check magento log file ?

Comment: The cause of this kind of issues are hard to guess without seeing the server logs / magento logs. Check your mysql server

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use many filters for layered navigation? When bots hit it if using sql search it will exceed max connections and lock things up and repeat over and over. One possible area to look at. I already had this issue and had to block all bad bots in robot.txt. Check mostly for Chinese bots and block by IP in htaccess or firewall tune robot.txt to instruct delay 10 for bots. Connect your site to cloudflare and tune things to disallow huge hits. In general, mostly Chinese bots are the ones who don't respect rules and robot.txt si personally blocked all China.